# Changing Group Policy via Java

Tags: java, powershell, cmd, group-policy, executionpolicy

I'm looking for a way to change the Execution Policy with scope MachinePolicy and UserPolicy from within a java programm (not via UI!). The powershell can't change these with the "set-executionPolicy" - command.

Changing it via the cmdlets in powershell (as recommended here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/ee461027(v=technet.10) ) is not possible because we want to use it without installing any other tools like rsat.

Also we don't want to change it with the lgpo.exe because the registry.pol has to be changed "by hand".

Are there any other ways to change it via cmd, a java-library or a executable that doesn't need to be installed?

OS: Windows 10

Comment: Security is not important for you it seems?

Comment: @KarelG It's used for an installer that has to run powershell scripts. So this is a must-have